# Inheritance - different files (C++)

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm trying out this inheritance tutorial in different files, .h and .cpp.

I've done the necessary `#include` of header files.
I couldn't figure out what is wrong with the code, when I am trying to run it.
It have the error stating that:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line

```
Error   C2011   'Person': 'class' type redefinition     
Error   C2027   use of undefined type 'Person'      
Error   C2065   'idNum': undeclared identifier  
Error   C2065   'lastName': undeclared identifier   
Error   C2065   'firstName': undeclared identifier      
Error   C2027   use of undefined type 'Person'      
Error   C2065   'idNum': undeclared identifier  
Error   C2065   'firstName': undeclared identifier      
Error   C2065   'lastName': undeclared identifier
```

below is my code:

**Person.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class Person {

private:
    int idNum;
    string lastName;
    string firstName;
public:
    void setFields(int, string, string);
    void outputData();


};

void Person::setFields(int num, string last, string first) {
    idNum = num;
    lastName = last;
    firstName = first;

}

void Person::outputData()
{
    cout << "ID #" << idNum << " Name: " << firstName << " " << lastName << endl;
}
```

**Customer.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Person.h"

using namespace std;
class Customer :public Person
{

private:
    double balanceDue;
public:
    void setBalDue(double);
    void outputBalDue();
};

void Customer::setBalDue(double bal) {
    balanceDue = bal;
}

void Customer::outputBalDue() {
    cout << "Balance due $ " << balanceDue << endl;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Customer.h"
#include "Person.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    Customer cust;
    //cust.setFields(215, "Santini", "Linda");
    //cust.outputData();
    cust.setBalDue(147.95);
    cust.outputBalDue();

    return 0;

}
```

Edit:
**Person.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H

using namespace std;
class Person {

private:
    int idNum;
    string lastName;
    string firstName;
public:
    void setFields(int, string, string);
    void outputData();


};

void Person::setFields(int num, string last, string first) {
    idNum = num;
    lastName = last;
    firstName = first;

}

void Person::outputData()
{
    cout << "ID #" << idNum << " Name: " << firstName << " " << lastName << endl;
}
#endif
```

Comment: search for : header include guards

Comment: Read about [*include guards*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

Comment: Then don't *define* functions in header files, unless you mark them as `inline` (explicitly or implicitly).

Comment: please dont edit your question by fixing the problem. If you do this, the question (and possible answers) will be of no use for future readers. Instead you can post the fixed code as an answer. You can even accept your own answer, if it solves the problem.

Comment: imho even this would be better as (partial) answer rather than an addition to the question. Just imagine someone who didnt follow the comments reads your question. He will not understand what is the point of this last section in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function definitions should be in a .cpp file, not in a .h file.

You need this:

**Customer.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Customer.h"

using namespace std;

void Customer::setBalDue(double bal) {
    balanceDue = bal;
}

void Customer::outputBalDue() {
    cout << "Balance due $ " << balanceDue << endl;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Customer.h"
#include "Person.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    Customer cust;
    //cust.setFields(215, "Santini", "Linda");
    //cust.outputData();
    cust.setBalDue(147.95);
    cust.outputBalDue();

    return 0;    
}
```

**Person.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Person.h"

void Person::setFields(int num, string last, string first) {
    idNum = num;
    lastName = last;
    firstName = first;    
}

void Person::outputData()
{
    cout << "ID #" << idNum << " Name: " << firstName << " " << lastName << endl;
}
```

In the header files you need [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

**Customer.h**

```
#ifndef _customer_inc_h_
#define _customer_inc_h_  // Include guard. This makes sure that
                          // Customer.h is included actually only once
                          // to avoid "multiple definition" errors

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Person.h"

using namespace std;

class Customer :public Person
{

private:
    double balanceDue;
public:
    void setBalDue(double);
    void outputBalDue();
};

#endif
```

**Person.h**

```
#ifndef _person_inc_h_
#define _person_inc_h_

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Person {

private:
    int idNum;
    string lastName;
    string firstName;
public:
    void setFields(int, string, string);
    void outputData();
};
#endif
```

Comment: sorry, why is it define as this way #ifndef _person_inc_h_
#define _person_inc_h_  instead of #ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H ?

Comment: @stack because he liked it that way? Header guard macro names do not have any meaning, they just need to be unique.

Comment: @MichaelWalz  isn't include guard look like this? #ifndef GRANDFATHER_H
#define GRANDFATHER_H

Comment: Actually, I still have error:
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Customer::outputBalDue(void)" (?outputBalDue@Customer@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function _main

Comment: @stack as Revolder_Ocelot has already written the symbol that comes after the `#ifndef` can be anything as long as it is unique (that is no two header files of your projectuse the same symbol). The name of the symbol is often like this: `_MYHEADERFILE_H_INC_` for clarity, but it could be `_ABdjdj4_fdf__fdff_`. It's up to you.

Comment: @stack it works here. Are you sure you have _linked/included_ the `Customer.cpp` file ? How do you compile your code ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz I'm using visual studio.. I've tried, and realise, the code is working when I comment away cust.setFields(215, "Santini", "Linda");  cust.outputData(); but when I didn't comment it, error occurs

Comment: @stack did you include `Customer.cpp` into your project?

Comment: Sorry, where should I include it?

Comment: @stack in your project.

Comment: I mean is it in the main.cpp?

Comment: Error LNK2005 "public: void __thiscall Customer::outputBalDue(void)" (?outputBalDue@Customer@@QAEXXZ) already defined in 

actually, this is my error

Comment: @stack BTW with Microsoft compilers at least, you can use [`#pragma once`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4141z1cx.aspx), which is more practical than the classic header include guards.

Comment: actually I'm quite new to CPP so not sure what is pragma.

Comment: @stack click on the `#pragma once` link in my previous comment. Otherwise google "c pragma".

Comment: @MichaelWalz Thanks for your help!(: